# Setting voice to 'en-GB' using WebSpeech API and webSpeechPonyfillFactory

Tags: botframework, webspeech-api

I am trying to set the `SpeechSynthesisVoice` to en-GB and gender to female in the `webSpeechPonyfillFactory` as provided in the example https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/06.f.hybrid-speech

I am not great at ponyfill and I tried passing the value to the Factory but it failed.

```js
  async createPonyfillFactory() {
    const webSpeechPonyfillFactory = await window.WebChat.createBrowserWebSpeechPonyfillFactory();
    return options => {
      const webSpeechPonyfill = webSpeechPonyfillFactory(options);

      return {
        SpeechGrammarList: webSpeechPonyfill.SpeechGrammarList,
        SpeechRecognition: webSpeechPonyfill.SpeechRecognition,
        speechSynthesis: webSpeechPonyfill.speechSynthesis,
        SpeechSynthesisUtterance: webSpeechPonyfill.SpeechSynthesisUtterance
      };
    };
  }
```

Comment: It looks like there may be a transient issue with the cognitive services API that handles TTS right now, fyi.

Answer (score 0):

You specify the locale and voice via the `selectVoice` properties sent to WebChat. For reference, this is demonstrated in sample [06.h.select-voice](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/06.g.select-voice#selecting-voice).

```js
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
  directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
    token,
    webSocket: true
  }),
  selectVoice: (voices, activity) =>
    activity.locale === 'zh-HK' ?
      voices.find(({ name }) => /TracyRUS/iu.test(name))
      :
      voices.find(({ name }) => /JessaNeural/iu.test(name))
      || voices.find(({ name }) => /Jessa/iu.test(name)),
  webSpeechPonyfillFactory
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

Hope of help!

Comment: Hey Steven - your example uses Cognitive services not the web speech API.I need to use Web Speech API and also as you can see from my code snippet, I am using react